# Crear funcion en Javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones

Requiero ayuda en lo siguiente

Tengo este codigo

```js
primer_array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    
    contactenos = "<ul>"
    primer_array.forEach(myLicontacto)
    contactenos += "</ul>"
    
    function myLicontacto(value) {
    contactenos += "<li>" + value + "</li>";
    }

document.write(contactenos)
```

Pero me gustaría convertirlo en una función que yo le pueda pasar cualquier otro arreglo y esta devuelva el resultado requerido, es decir:

```js
segundo_array = ['SSS', 'DDD', 'FFF', 'GGG']
    
    resultado = "<ul>"
    segundo_array.forEach(myLiResultado)
    resultado += "</ul>"
    
    function myLiResultado(value) {
    resultado += "<li>" + value + "</li>";
    }

document.write(resultado)
```

Intente haciendo algo como esto y lógicamente no funciono estoy algo mal con mi logica:

```
// a es el arreglo
// b es el nombre de la variable que se viene declarando
```

```js
prueba = ['qqq','www','eee'];
resultado = myLiArray(prueba,'respuesta');

function myLiArray(a,b) {
    b = "<ul>"    b += "<li>" + a.forEach(element =element) + "</li>";
    b += "<ul>"
    }
    
    document.write(resultado)
```

El nombre de la variable b puede ser resultado, glosario, autores, cantantes, musicas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
prueba = ['qqq','www','eee'];
resultado = myLiArray(prueba);

// 1. El parámetro b no es necesario
function myLiArray(a) {
    let b = "<ul>";

    // 2. Se llama a forEach y se le pasa una función anónima
    // para concatenar los elementos
    a.forEach(e => {
      b += `<li> ${e} </li>`
    });
    b += "<ul>"
    // 3. Se retorna el nuevo resultado
    return b;
}
    
document.write(resultado)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya que @Lobos te ofreció una respuesta usando el código que muestras, te voy a ofrecer unas ideas adicionales que pueden ser útiles para quienes se acercan a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).
En el caso particular que planteas, concatenación de elementos de un array, no es necesario iterar sobre sus elementos. Los arrays poseen el método `join()` dispuesto para hacer la tarea. La iteración es necesaria **cuando se necesita hacer algo más que concatenar** con los elementos individuales o con algunos de ellos. (Usarla para concatenar, en cierto sentido, es hacer algo como cazar pollitos usando misiles)

De modo que para generar una lista como la que necesitas basta escribir algo como:

```js
let prueba = ['qqq','www','eee'];
// nota el uso "inverso" de las etiquetas de cierre y apertura del elemento li
let lista = '<ul><li>'+prueba.join('</li><li>')+'</li></ul>';
document.write(lista);
```

Para convertirlo en una función que admita un array como entrada basta ponerle nombre e incluir la línea dentro de un bloque así:

```js
function crearListaDesdeArray(entrada){
    return '<ul><li>'+entrada.join('</li><li>')+'</li></ul>';
}

let prueba = ['qqq','www','eee'];
document.write(crearListaDesdeArray(prueba));
```

Answer (score 1):

Tomando en cuenta que JavaScript es un lenguaje interpretado (con un flujo descendente de ejecución), te conviene no combinar HTML dentro de JS, por ende una solución bien práctica y correcta sería:

```js
const arreglo = ['qqq','www','eee'];
const lista = document.querySelector(".miLista");

function myLiArray(a, b) {
    a.forEach(e => {
      b.innerHTML += `<li> ${e} </li>`
    });
    return b;
}

resultado = myLiArray(arreglo, lista);

document.write(resultado);
```

```html
<ul class="miLista">
      
<ul>
```

Ten siempre en cuenta lo siguiente:

- La ejecución es interpretada (de arriba a abajo)
- Mientras menos HTML ligues dentro de JS mejor